# Using binary search for finding the number that appears odd number of times in an array of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I am able to do it for my first example but for example 2, I am not able to get the right answer. My code actually looks for the middle position and traverse the array to the right side of the array as mid -1 = mid, which makes the condition true but mid -1 = mid -2. What should I do for ignoring this?

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

class Lab4 {
// Function to return k'th smallest
// element in a given array


public static int findOddNumber(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {

    int mid = 0;
    mid = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2;

    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        return numbers[startIndex];
    }
    if (mid % 2 == 0) {
        if (numbers[mid] == numbers[mid + 1]) {
            return findOddNumber(numbers, mid + 2, endIndex);
        } else {
            return findOddNumber(numbers, startIndex, mid);
        }
    } else {
        if (numbers[mid] == numbers[mid - 1])
            return findOddNumber(numbers, mid + 1, endIndex);
        else
            return findOddNumber(numbers, startIndex, mid - 1);
    }
}

// driver program
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int arr2[] = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5 };
    System.out.println("Odd number is " + findOddNumber(arr2, 0, arr2.length - 1));

    int arr3[] = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6 };
    System.out.println("Odd number is " + findOddNumber(arr3, 0, arr3.length-1));

    }

}
```

Comment: How exactly do you intend for binary search to solve this problem? Are you guaranteed that the input array will be in order (your question doesn't say so)? Please edit your question to add more details about what you are trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Binary search is only useful for finding elements that are *sorted*, which you have not stated is the case. I would iterate across the data and build a map of the value and how many times it has been encountered. After iterating, you can find which elements have odd counts. There are some minor optimizations you can make, but I think you will have to iterate over all elements as a minimum. If elements are known to be sorted (you examples are), you can iterate over the whole array and stop when you find the first odd-count number, but that still has O(n) time complexity.

Comment: Was it stipulated to use a binary search?

Comment: @kaya3 yes it is guaranteed that input array will be always sorted. I am trying to find the number which appears odd number of times.

Comment: @Bohemian I wan to solve it in O(log(n)) complexity, otherwise I could have used XOR or bitwise. The array will be always sorted

Comment: @AndyMan yes, I have to do in O(logn) time. For that binary search is the best I guess. If you have any opinions, please feel free to give it to me.

Comment: If the array is always sorted, then there is a solution which is should be O(log n) in the average case and probably a bit higher than O(log n) in the worst case; maybe O(log^2 n). But your code doesn't look close to it. I think you need to think more carefully about how the algorithm should work before you start writing any code; come up with your algorithm and work through a few examples on paper to get the design right first.

Comment: I think the error you have made is that you are assuming every element appears either 1 or 2 times.

Comment: So to ignore that I made this condition @kaya3 , but now I increased the repeated number to 7 and it gives me StackOverflow error.                               
       if(startIndex < mid -2 && numbers[mid -1] == numbers[mid -2]) {
      return findOddNumber(numbers,startIndex,mid-2); 
     }

Comment: Step away from the code, and design an algorithm. Don't try to convert the solution in your head into Java until the solution in your head is definitely correct.

Comment: How does a binary search help? Finding a number from a sorted list with a BS means you can find your number efficiently by dividing the list in half each iteration. Here there is no such advantage, because you need the number of occurrences of each number.

Comment: @AndyMan if you will notice elements are repeating in a certain manner at odd position and even position which leads to conditions. condtion 1 if mid is odd and condition 1.1 if mid = mid -1 then reqd number is on right or else it is at left. condition 2 if number is even 2.1 if mid = mid +1 number could be at left or else it is at right. according to this I have designed this algorithm.

Comment: You can't use binary search to find a number that appears an odd number of times.  You *can* use it to find a number that appears exactly once when everything else appears twice in a row.

Comment: @MattTimmermans then how can I do it in O(log(n)) times?

Comment: You can't.  I think you have the question wrong

Comment: @MattTimmermans I did it. I do not want to offend you but this was a question given by my Instructor and he is really good. Anyways thanks for your message, I really appreciate that.

Comment: @MattTimmermans there is an algorithm for this problem that looks like binary search, but it's a bit more complicated than this. If you look in the middle and see the value `x`, then you have to find the left-most and right-most occurrences of `x` to know whether the answer is to the left or right, or is `x` itself. You can use a second binary search to find the left-most and right-most occurrences. So the algorithm ends up doing binary search about `2 log_2 n` times, for a worst case of something like O(log^2 n).

Comment: @kaya3, yes that certainly works, but I don't think you can do it in O(log n) time.

Comment: I think there might be a variant that does better than O(log^2 n) by doing a linear search over fewer than `log n` elements to the left and the right before falling back to binary search. I'm not sure that isn't still O(log^2 n) anyway; but I'm also not sure that O(log n) is impossible. I think it's probably fair to say that either the statement of the problem here is not quite right, or it's an extension exercise the instructor didn't expect most students to be able to do, or the instructor made a (quite subtle) mistake.

Comment: @DESIRECORDS modified my answer and added code example to solve it based on yours and kaya's ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I understand your solution now. One of the problems is that just by looking at the element to the right or the left of mid you still can't know which way to go. So here is an adaption: Find the last index with the same value as the value for mid using binary search. If it is odd, then you have to search in the subarray right of that index, otherwise you have to look on the left side. Time complexity O((logn)^2), but only works for ordered arrays with exactly one element appearing an odd number of times. In code:

```
public static int findOddNumber(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (numbers[startIndex] == numbers[endIndex])
        return numbers[startIndex];
    int mid = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2;
    int last = findLast(numbers, mid, endIndex);
    if (last % 2 == 1)
        return findOddNumber(numbers, last + 1, endIndex);
    else
        return findOddNumber(numbers, startIndex, mid - mid % 2);
}

private static int findLast(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (numbers[startIndex] == numbers[endIndex])
        return endIndex;
    int mid = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2;
    if (numbers[startIndex] == numbers[mid])
        return findLast(numbers, mid, endIndex - 1);
    else
        return findLast(numbers, startIndex, mid - 1);
}
```

---

For unordered arrays there are much simpler ways to find all the odd numbers using a hash set. This also works for multiple odd numbers. Just go through the array and if a number is already in the set remove it otherwise add it. In the end you have all numbers that appear an odd number of times in the hash set. This takes O(n) time and space.

If you know that there is exactly one number appearing an odd number of times, then you can just xor all the array values and get the solution. O(n) time and O(1) space. This also works for unordered arrays.

Comment: Why would you suggest `O(n log n)` when we can solve this in `O((log n)^2)` ?

Comment: That's correct, we don't have to look at all the elements. OP said the array is sorted, there is only one number with an odd count, and kaya3 described the O((log n)^2) algorithm in the comments.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I see, but this only works if the array is sorted and there is exactly one element which appears an odd number of times.

Comment: That's what the OP said. In English, using "the," means there's a specific one (from the comments: "I am trying to find the number which appears odd number of times.")

Comment: Hi @maraca It does not works for  {1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,7,7 } .

Comment: @DESIRECORDS for me it works, you probably missed the update 25 mins ago, in the first else there is not just mid, but mid - mid % 2 to make the number of elements in the range odd. Otherwise you can indeed construct examples where the algorithm fails.

Comment: @DESIRECORDS Although this is not one of them, maybe you used the length of the wrong array (either directly or for the length) when calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's a sorted array, the best "worst case time complexity" you can get is O(n). It is so because the worst case scenario is when all the elements in the array are different and occur just once each.
(For example -> 1,2,3,4,5)

And the O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity solution would be to iterate through the array with a curr_element (Storing the curr_element which might be repeating), a count variable(To count occurences of curr_element) and a total variable(answer to the question) extra. Iterate, count occurences of curr_element and if it is odd, increment total.

There can't be any solution better than O(n) in this case.

Comment: You probably misread, as the problem is not stated very clear, If there is just one subsequence of odd length, indeed a binary search might help.

Answer (score 0):

A binary search is possible by the length of subranges.

One has to ensure that the subranges come from splitting a range such that
the second subrange starts with a different value as the first ends with.

Your solution did not loop for splitting. Also the oddness of the *length* of the subrange, not the `mid` index must be checked.

```
public static int findOddNumber(int[] numbers) {
    return findOddNumber(numbers, 0, numbers.length);
}
```

with a recursive binary splitting:

```
/**
 * @param numbers where only one value occurs an odd number of times.
 * @param startIndex.
 * @param endIndex exclusive.
 */
public static int findOddNumber(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    assert endIndex - startIndex % 2 == 1;

    if (endIndex - startIndex == 1) {
        return numbers[startIndex];
    }
    // Now at least two elements.

    // Try to split into two subranges, the first ending with a different value
    // as the second subrange.
    int mid = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2;

    // Do not split inside subrange of the same number:
    int split = mid + 1;
    while (split < endIndex && numbers[split] == numbers[split - 1]) {
        ++split;
    }
    if (split == endIndex) {
        split = mid;
        while (split > startIndex && numbers[split] == numbers[split - 1]) {
            --split;
        }
    }
    if (split == startIndex || split == endIndex) { // Could not split.
        return numbers[startIndex]; // All numbers the same.
    }
    if ((split - startIndex) % 2 == 1) {
        return findOddNumberIndex(numbers, startIndex, split);
    } else {
        return findOddNumberIndex(numbers, split, endIndex);
    }
}
```

Now the split could use a binary search (Arrays.binarySearch) to find begin and end, by searching numbers[mid] + or - 0.5 but that is not feasible here.

---

As curiosity an alternative solution, when the numbers are not ordered:

```
public static int findOddNumber(int[] numbers) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int n : numbers) {
        retult ^= n;
    }
    return n;
}
```

This utilizes x^x == 0 and 0^x == x. ^ (XOR) being commutative and associative.

Comment: Wouldn't your algorithm be `O(n)` provided with an array with an odd count of the same number? Couldn't we also use binary search to find the highest and lowest indexes of any repeated number (in a sorted array)?